# Is validation script causing issues with my javascript to Show/Hide DIVs?

Tags: javascript, validation

Screen shot of what's happening: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBkfF.png

My test buttons: http://jsfiddle.net/KtrQh/8/

I'm using an older Validatious script for our validation.

What I'd like to do is have the Shipping Address collapsed/hidden, with two buttons above it. One is "Same as billing", the other is "Add shipping address". Once you click "Add shipping address", the Shipping Address is then shown.

Any ideas? I'm not sure why the validation is happening when I hit "Show DIV" (testing text btw); that should simply hide/show the Shipping Area instead of all of a sudden running validation on all of my fields.

The thing is, I'm using a SaaS vendor named Kalio Commerce. You'll see a ton of their API code in the jsfiddle, so I'm not very sure how to express that in the jsfiddle. But I wanted to share the code overall with you too, so you'd have the big picture.

Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you place a live example up? Your jsfiddle wasn't working for me. Style tip: consider creating a css class that has "display:none" and add and remove that css class trigger hiding and showing elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I handle this on Blog is,

```
<div id="box1" class="hide">Hidden Content</div>
<a onmousedown="showContent()">Show Content</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script>
function showContent(){

    if(document.getElementById('box1').className == "hide"){
       document.getElementById('box1').className = "show";
    }
    else{
       document.getElementById('box1').className = "hide";
    }
}
</script>
```

CSS:

```
div.hide
{
    display: none;
}
div.show
{
    display: block;
}
```

Sorry if I have misinterpreted the question.

Comment: Am I able to use the onmousedown for buttons or checkboxes?

Comment: onmousedown was an example, you can call the method a range of ways. E.g. <input type="button" onclick="showContent();" />

Comment: I see! Very nice. Learning so much recently about JS, very powerful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Create a CSS class like this:

```
.invisible
{
    display: none;
}
```

and add invisible to the tags which you want to disappear. When you want a tag to reappear, remove the invisible class. You should prevent the button from posting if you don't want to post when you click on them.